# display popup for 1 second only in windows phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

Snapshot is taken and user should be notified that its saved in library.I am trying to use popup.Is there any other way?
and if not popup should appear on an event and should close automatically after 1 second.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's the [`Popup`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/system.windows.controls.primitives.popup%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) control that's been available since Windows Phone 7.

Create the popup, show it and set a timer for one second. When the timer expires, close the popup.

Comment: can u tell me,how to create a timer please?

Comment: Use a DispatcherTimer: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatchertimer.aspx